# How do I filter a collection in a jinja2 template ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, jinja2

I have a collection of namedtuples which looks like this :

```
[('mountpoint=X',state='UP'),(mountpoint='Y',state='DOWN'),(mountpoint='Z',state='DOWN'...)]
```

I pass this collection to one of my templates. I'd like to filter that collection based on state. Tried the following to no avail

```
  {% for state in states|selectattr('state','down') %}
TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'down'

  {% for state in states|selectattr(state='down') %}
FilterArgumentError: Missing parameter for attribute name

  {% for state in states|select(state='down') %}
No error, but doesn't filter at all.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`equalto`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#equalto) test:

```
{% for state in states|selectattr('state', 'equalto', 'down') %}
```

Comment: `{% for state in states|selectattr("state","equalto","DOWN") %}` -> `TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto'`

Comment: Maybe a problem of jinja2 version then. I have 2.7.3

Comment: @ychaouche: it was added in Jinja 2.8.

Comment: Tried the "sameas" test in jinja2.7.3 which, for this special case, works fine because I'm comparing strings ?

Comment: @ychaouche: this means that strings were [cached](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/2301450). You shouldn't rely on that behaviour.